# In modules, basis, minimal spanning set, maximal linearly independent set do not coincide

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I am a postgraduate first year student. I have studied vector spaces in undergraduate course. In postgraduate course, we are studying modules. Our instructor mentioned in one of his lectures that in modules, the concept of basis, minimal spanning set, maximal linearly independent set are different, they do not coincide as in vector spaces. Can someone give me an example where these do not coincide.

Comment: See the contrasts on p. 10 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/moduleintro.pdf.

Comment: Consider the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}$ a module over $\mathbb{Z}$:

$\{2\}$ is a maximal linearly independent system, but not a basis;

$\{2,3\}$ minimal spanning set, but not the basis, since this system is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$.